# Status bar stays black when switching between light and dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm having a weird issue with the status bar where it stays black even when changing to dark mode.

When launching the app in dark mode, the status bar text is white as expected. Switching to light mode changes the status bar color to black. So far so good. However, if we switch back to dark mode, it stays black when it should've been white.

I've tried to replicate this issue into an another fresh project, but everything is behaving as expected.

The `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key is set to `true` and the "Status Bar Style" is set to `default`.

Has anyone faced this kind of behaviour and if so, what was the cause?

Answer (score 1):

In your View Controller, you need to implement the `preferredStatusBarStyle`.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
     return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

Or instead of `.lightContent` could be `.default` or `.darkContent`. This last one "darkContent" is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

**Edit: Using the Interface Style to choose between the correct color:**
If you are trying to use the Interface Style, maybe can be working on this way

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
    case .light:
        return .darkContent
    case .dark:
        return .lightContent
    case .unspecified:
        return .default
    @unknown default:
        return.default
    }
}
```

As well you can do it as extension of UINavigationController

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
        case .light:
            return .darkContent
        case .dark:
            return .lightContent
        case .unspecified:
            return .default
        @unknown default:
            return.default
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand if I wanted to force one of the other, but I want `.default` which should already be the value.

Comment: You can use the userInterfaceStyle to control which  Status Bar color display

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is not what I am looking for. My issue is that the `UIindowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarStyle` returns `darkContent` in dark mode even though the view controller is configured to use `.default`. It should normally return `.lightContent`.

Comment: Same issue here